# Declaring the maximum Value of an int

Tags: java, int

I'm designing a program to draw random boxes inside a JPanel, is there a way to declare an integers max value? The program says it must be a random height and width but I must remain inside the confines of the JPanel.

Comment: "declare an integers max value??" what do you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Integer.MAX_VALUE
```

Unless of course you're trying to set a custom max value. Then you would need to read the Random documentation to do something like this.

```
public class TestingStuff {
  public final int MAX;

  TestingStuff() {    
    Random r = new Random();
    MAX = r.nextInt(Math.abs(r.nextInt()));
    System.out.println(MAX);
  }

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    TestingStuff t = new TestingStuff();    
  }
}
```

While creating this I had issues declaring MAX as static and initializing it. It would seem that you can either make it static or final.